# How to insert a new record to the table created in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, email

I created a table in mysql as'cus_info'. It has columns as 'iD' 'NAME' 'PASSWORD' 'eMAIL'. iD column is auto increment. I want to insert a new row to this table when a new customer registered. For that I wrote the following code in PHP

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require "init.php";

$name = $_POST["name"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$email = $_POST["email"];



$sql = "INSERT INTO `cus_info` (`name`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$password."', '".$email."');";
if(!mysql_query($con, $sql)){
    echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
}

?>
```

but always I get the message as "unable to save data to the database"
Could you please tell me where I have gone wrong?
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: beside using `mysql_*` function and a code open to sql injection? `mysql_query` first parameter is `$sql`

Comment: Remove `;` inside the `" "` in the end

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` turns error messages ***off.*** Change it to `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: show your $con.also syntax error in query.

Comment: this is your custom message, we need the actual error message.try this:if(!mysqli_query($currentConnection, $sql)) {
    echo mysqli_error($currentConnection);
} & let us know the exact message.

Answer (score 0):

> Could you please tell me where I have gone wrong?

In more than one place.

To most directly answer your question, you can use [mysql_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to print the error you're getting from mysql.  To even more directly answer it, you have swapped the order of the parameters and you don't need the semicolon to be included in the query.  (See example code [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).)

You shouldn't be using PHP's "mysql_*" functions, which were [deprecated in PHP5.5 and even removed in PHP7](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).  You also should not be passing user input from a form directly into a MySQL database without any cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

First show your **$con** and then put **error_reporting(1)** to check if other error occurs.

And finnaly copy and replace in your code.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `cus_info` (`name`, `password`, `email`) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$password."', '".$email."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<?php
    error_reporting(0);
    require "init.php";
    if(isset($_REQUEST["save"]))
    {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];     
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `cus_info` (`name`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('$name','$password','$email')");
    $values=mysql_insert_id();
    if($values!='')
    {
       echo '{"message":"Successfully save the data to the database."}';
    }
    else
    {
    echo '{"message":"Unable to save the data to the database."}';
    }
     }
    ?>
```